# Transformer do not work in DC (50Hz) digital signal?

Tags: electromagnetism, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

**condition 1:** By passing DC current through copper coil it generate the magnetic field.

**condition 2:** By moving magnet around cooper wire it generate current.

When DC current of 50Hz passes through the primary coil of transformer it will be generating some magnetic filed around primary coil. (**condition 1 = true**)

The magnetic field will affect the secondary coil as it is close to primary coil. thus there should be some current in secondary coil.(as per **condition 2**)

I have digital signal of 5V(+5,0) at 50Hz using [arduino uno](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) and transformer 12-0-12 1A.

[image: DC]

**Update:** (connected secondary coil of 0-12V)

input 5V DC at 50Hz = output 5.1V

input 5V DC at 100Hz = output 8.7V

input 5V DC at 1KHz = output 18.1V

current is very low around 1 mA. but when i measure current for 1 second it becomes zero.

I have checked output values in AC voltage of [multimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter) .

**Why DC is not working with transformer?** seems to be working now kind of but not sure if output voltage is actually AC?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Electrical Engineering won't allow me to ask  question :(

Comment: It would work if you had superconducting coils and tunnel junctions for detectors... but you don't. In an ordinary transformer you always have an RL circuit because of the finite resistance of the windings and the finite inductance of the coil, and that will cause a high-pass effect. You can still transmit digital signals, but you have to modulate them with a code that removes the dc bias. This could be a Manchester code or something more complex like an 8B/10B code.

Answer (score 1):

The signal you are injecting into the transformer is not the plain DC, but the switched or chopped DC.

Transformer needs changes in its input current so that its magnetic field will change accordingly. Only the fluctuating magnetic field will induce electromotive force in the secondary winding.

Having said this, with chopped DC is being supplied into primary, there will be output voltage generated in the secondary. But the output will be AC, not sinusoidal but more like distorted square wave.

For every input pulse, the AC output will rise with its leading edge overshoot positively, decay exponentially towards zero and then overshoot at negative, decay  towards zero.